# Cloud Build Failed to trigger build: generic::permission_denied: Permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to use a use cloud build for my cloud run project. I have this cloudbuild.json:

```
{
  "steps": [
    {
      "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker",
      "args": ["build", "-t", "eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/keysafe", "."]
    },
    {
      "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker",
      "args": [
        "push",
        "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/my-docker-repo/myimage"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "options": {
    "logging": "CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY"
  }
}
```

And I keep getting a permission denied error. I've tried running it without a service account and using my permissions (I'm the owner), and with a service account even with the owner role.

It was originally working but since my project transitioned from Container registry to Artifact repository, I was getting an error

```
generic::invalid_argument: generic::invalid_argument: if 'build.service_account' is specified, the build must either (a) specify 'build.logs_bucket' (b) use the CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY logging option, or (c) use the NONE logging option
```

That error persisted through both my account and the service account, which is why I switched to building from a cloudbuild.json file, not just my Dockerfile alone.

All the other Stack Overflow articles I've found suggest permissions to assign, but the service account and I have owner permissions and even adding the suggested permissions on top of Owner did not help.

Here are the permissions of the service account:
[image]

Here is the trigger configuration:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: IIUC, the error is not consistent with the `cloudbuild.json` that you include in your question. `build.service_account` is probably (!) the [`serviceAccount`](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#Build.FIELDS.service_account) (maps to `service_account` in JSON) of the [Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#Build). Which according to the `cloudbuild.json` you include, is not being used. Either, there's more to the `cloudbuild.json` **or** you're not using the config that you think you are.

Comment: It's possible that you're specifying the Service Account on the command line (please include) and this is overriding the value.

Comment: @DazWilkin I've edited the post to include the service account permissions and the trigger details. The cloudbuild.json I put originally is the entire file.

Comment: One other issue is that you `docker build` for GCR but you `docker push` to Artifact Registry. This will fail. You should probably build|push the same image name (including the Artifact Registry prefix) or you need to `docker tag ${GCR image} ${GAR image}`

Comment: I'm unable to repro your issue unfortunately. Even with the build for GCR, push to Analytics Registry error intentionally introduced, the build fails only at the step. I'm unable to repro the `invalid_argument` error using a user-defined service account and `CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ends up in my position this is how I fixed it.

I ended up deleting the Cloud Run and Build and then recreated them. This gave me a pre-made cloudbuild.yaml which I added the option `logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY`, still using the same service account. I'm not sure why this fixed it but it does seem to be working.